# Oracle ordim jar missing

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jakarta-ee, dependencies

I am unable to find the maven dependency for `oracle ordim`

Below lines exist in my current pom.xml done by earlier developers.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.ordim</groupId>
    <artifactId>ordim</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

I tried downloading externally but not able to find the right jar

Error I see

> Missing artifact com.oracle.ordim:ordim:jar:11.2.0

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "earlier developers" were either using a repository manager such as Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva - or had manually installed this dependency into their local maven repository (using maven install:install-file).

As a general rule you will not find Oracle jars in any public maven repository because they are licensed products. Even if free you need to agree to a licence agreement before downloading them.